# Switching from context menu to correct activity

Tags: android, android-intent

My problem is how to switch from context menu to correct activity.

I have such activities:

- `Main`
- `AccelerometerOptionsActivity`
- `GyroscopeOptionsActivity`
- `OrientationOptionsActivity`

In main activity I have a list of sensors. When I click the sensor, context menu appears where I can click e.g. Options.

My problem is how to switch from context menu to options  activity of chosen sensor. 
My code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
      int menuItemIndex = item.getItemId();
      String[] menuItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sensor_array);
      String menuItemName = menuItems[menuItemIndex];


      if(item.getTitle()=="Start Service"){
          Toast.makeText(this,"Start " + menuItemName+ " selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      } else if(item.getTitle()=="Stop Service") {
          Toast.makeText(this,"Stop " + menuItemName+ " selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      } else if(item.getTitle()=="Options") {


              Intent options = new Intent(this, AccelerometerOptionsActivity.class);
                startActivity(options);

      }

      return true;   
    }
```

UPDATE:

Here is the code:

```
 @Override 
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) { 
         if (v.getId()==R.id.list) {  
            AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;  

            menu.setHeaderTitle(sensorsArray[info.position]);
            menu.add(Menu.NONE, CONTEXTMENU_START, 0,  "Start Service");
            menu.add(Menu.NONE, CONTEXTMENU_STOP, 1,  "Stop Service");
            menu.add(Menu.NONE, CONTEXTMENU_OPTIONS, 2, "Options"); 
            menu.add(Menu.NONE, CONTEXTMENU_GRAPHS, 3, "Graph view");
            menu.add(Menu.NONE, CONTEXTMENU_DATA, 4, "Data view");
         }  
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a `ListView` with the sensors on which(the list) you set the `ContextMenu`?

Comment: Post the code where you display the context menu.

Comment: Yes I have a ListView with the sensors when I click the name of the sensor the ContextMenu appears. I add the code in above question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your `onContextItemSelected()`:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
                    .getMenuInfo();
        int menuItemIndex = item.getItemId(); // the position of the item in the list with the context menu
        String[] menuItems =  getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sensor_array);
        String menuItemName = menuItems[menuItemIndex];
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case CONTEXTMENU_START:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Start " + menuItemName + " selected",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
        case CONTEXTMENU_STOP:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Stop " + menuItemName + " selected",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
            case CONTEXTMENU_OPTIONS:
        // here start the correct options activity either by checking for
        // String equality with menuItemName or by doing a switch on the menuItemIndex(this works
        // if your list of sensors is based on the array R.array.sensor_array)
            switch (menuItemIndex) {
              case 0:
              //the user clicked the first sensor in the list so start that option activity           
              break;
              case 1:
                //the user clicked the second sensor in the list so start that option activity
                  break;
              }
      }
      return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it's not working. I debug the code and it's omitting the switch statement.

Comment: @erni In my code above replace `int menuItemIndex = item.getItemId();` with `int menuItemIndex = info.position;`

Answer (score 0):

Use .contains(yourString) method instead of == . 
e.g. Replace

```
if(item.getTitle()=="Options") {...
```

with

```
if(item.getTitle().contains("Options") {...
```

Comment: I changed this to switch. But this is not my problem. My problem is to get to proper Activity.

Comment: Your code looks fine except for that == part. Replace it and see. Try to debug if posible and see if its hitting the breakpoint. If you are getting any exception or something, put the log from the logcat with your question.

Comment: I think that you don't understand my problem. I want to be directed to proper Options activity e.g. I choose accelerometer and from the context menu I want to go to accelerometer options. I choose orientation service and from the context menu I want to go to orientation options et cetera.== this part works fine. Regards